# error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Signature` in crate `signature`

Tags: runtime-upgrade, error, build

I am currently upgrading our chain to polkadot-v0.9.38 but when I run the build I get the following error:

```
error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Signature` in crate `signature`
   --> /home/albrayanov/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ed25519-1.5.2/src/lib.rs:335:17
    |
335 | impl signature::Signature for Signature {
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `signature`
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this since the **signature::Signature** implementation is not defined in our code (link to the branch can be found [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/runtime-upgrade/polkadot-v0.9.38))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use the command cargo update and Then let me know

Comment: Thanks seems to work after ```cargo update```